# Instance member can't be accessed using static access while using intercom_flutter.dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, intercom

I'm getting the following errors in my flutter app when attempting to use intercom_flutter.dart package.

```
Instance member 'initialize' can't be accessed using static access.
Instance member 'displayMessenger' can't be accessed using static access.
Instance member 'registerIdentifiedUser' can't be accessed using static access.
Instance member 'logout' can't be accessed using static access.
```

The code which shows the error :

```html
void bootstrap(
      {required String iosApiKey,
      required String androidApiKey,
      required String appId}) async {
    this.iosApiKey = iosApiKey;
    this.androidApiKey = androidApiKey;
    this.appId = appId;
    await Intercom.initialize(appId,
        iosApiKey: iosApiKey, androidApiKey: androidApiKey);
  }

  Future displayMessenger() {
    return Intercom.displayMessenger();
  }

  Future enableIntercom() async {
    await disableIntercom();
    User? loggedInUser = _userService.getLoggedInUser();
    if (loggedInUser == null) throw 'Cannot enable intercom. Not logged in.';

    assert(loggedInUser.uuid != null && loggedInUser.id != null);

    String userId = _makeUserId(loggedInUser);
    return Intercom.registerIdentifiedUser(userId: userId);
  }

  Future disableIntercom() {
    return Intercom.logout();
  }

  String _makeUserId(User user) {
    var bytes = utf8.encode(user.uuid! + user.id.toString());
    var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
  }
}
```

The intercom_flutter.dart code is the following :

```html
class Intercom {
  /// private constructor to not allow the object creation from outside.
  Intercom._();

  static final Intercom _instance = Intercom._();

  /// get the instance of the [Intercom].
  static Intercom get instance => _instance;

  /// Function to initialize the Intercom SDK.
  ///
  /// First, you'll need to get your Intercom [appId].
  /// [androidApiKey] is required if you want to use Intercom in Android.
  /// [iosApiKey] is required if you want to use Intercom in iOS.
  ///
  /// You can get these from Intercom settings:
  /// * [Android](https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/_/settings/android)
  /// * [iOS](https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/_/settings/ios)
  ///
  /// Then, initialize Intercom in main method.
  Future<void> initialize(
    String appId, {
    String? androidApiKey,
    String? iosApiKey,
  }) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance
        .initialize(appId, androidApiKey: androidApiKey, iosApiKey: iosApiKey);
  }

  /// You can check how many unread conversations a user has
  /// even if a user dismisses a notification.
  ///
  /// You can listen for unread conversation count with this method.
  Stream<dynamic> getUnreadStream() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.getUnreadStream();
  }

  /// This method allows you to set a fixed bottom padding for in app messages and the launcher.
  ///
  /// It is useful if your app has a tab bar or similar UI at the bottom of your window.
  /// [padding] is the size of the bottom padding in points.
  Future<void> setBottomPadding(int padding) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.setBottomPadding(padding);
  }

  /// To make sure that conversations between you and your users are kept private
  /// and that one user can't impersonate another then you need you need to setup
  /// the identity verification.
  ///
  /// This function helps to set up the identity verification.
  /// Here you need to pass hash (HMAC) of the user.
  ///
  /// This must be called before registering the user in Intercom.
  ///
  /// To generate the user hash (HMAC) see
  /// <https://gist.github.com/thewheat/7342c76ade46e7322c3e>
  ///
  /// Note: identity verification does not apply to unidentified users.
  Future<void> setUserHash(String userHash) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.setUserHash(userHash);
  }

  /// Function to create a identified user in Intercom.
  /// You need to register your users before you can talk to them and
  /// track their activity in your app.
  ///
  /// You can register a identified user either with [userId] or with [email],
  /// but not with both.
  @Deprecated("use loginIdentifiedUser")
  Future<void> registerIdentifiedUser({String? userId, String? email}) {
    return loginIdentifiedUser(userId: userId, email: email);
  }

  /// Function to create a identified user in Intercom.
  /// You need to register your users before you can talk to them and
  /// track their activity in your app.
  ///
  /// You can register a identified user either with [userId] or with [email],
  /// but not with both.
  Future<void> loginIdentifiedUser(
      {String? userId, String? email, IntercomStatusCallback? statusCallback}) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.loginIdentifiedUser(
        userId: userId, email: email, statusCallback: statusCallback);
  }

  /// Function to create a unidentified user in Intercom.
  /// You need to register your users before you can talk to them and
  /// track their activity in your app.
  @Deprecated("use loginUnidentifiedUser")
  Future<void> registerUnidentifiedUser() {
    return loginUnidentifiedUser();
  }

  /// Function to create a unidentified user in Intercom.
  /// You need to register your users before you can talk to them and
  /// track their activity in your app.
  Future<void> loginUnidentifiedUser({IntercomStatusCallback? statusCallback}) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance
        .loginUnidentifiedUser(statusCallback: statusCallback);
  }

  /// Updates the attributes of the current Intercom user.
  ///
  /// The [signedUpAt] param should be seconds since epoch.
  ///
  /// The [language] param should be an an ISO 639-1 two-letter code such as `en` for English or `fr` for French.
  /// You’ll need to use a four-letter code for Chinese like `zh-CN`.
  /// check this link https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/180-localize-intercom-to-work-with-multiple-languages.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///  * [Localize Intercom to work with multiple languages](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/180-localize-intercom-to-work-with-multiple-languages)
  Future<void> updateUser({
    String? email,
    String? name,
    String? phone,
    String? company,
    String? companyId,
    String? userId,
    int? signedUpAt,
    String? language,
    Map<String, dynamic>? customAttributes,
    IntercomStatusCallback? statusCallback,
  }) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.updateUser(
      email: email,
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      company: company,
      companyId: companyId,
      userId: userId,
      signedUpAt: signedUpAt,
      language: language,
      customAttributes: customAttributes,
      statusCallback: statusCallback,
    );
  }

  /// To logout a user from Intercom.
  /// This clears the Intercom SDK's cache of your user's identity.
  Future<void> logout() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.logout();
  }

  /// To hide or show the standard launcher on the bottom right-hand side of the screen.
  Future<void> setLauncherVisibility(IntercomVisibility visibility) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.setLauncherVisibility(visibility);
  }

  /// You can check how many unread conversations a user has
  /// even if a user dismisses a notification.
  ///
  /// You can get the current unread conversation count with this method.
  Future<int> unreadConversationCount() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.unreadConversationCount();
  }

  /// To allow or prevent in app messages from popping up in certain parts of your app.
  Future<void> setInAppMessagesVisibility(IntercomVisibility visibility) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance
        .setInAppMessagesVisibility(visibility);
  }

  /// To open the Intercom messenger.
  ///
  /// This is used when you manually want to launch Intercom messenger.
  /// for e.g: from your custom launcher (Help & Support) or (Talk to us).
  Future<void> displayMessenger() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displayMessenger();
  }

  /// To close the Intercom messenger.
  ///
  /// This is used when you manually want to close Intercom messenger.
  Future<void> hideMessenger() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.hideMessenger();
  }

  /// To display an Activity with your Help Center content.
  ///
  /// Make sure Help Center is turned on.
  /// If you don't have Help Center enabled in your Intercom settings the method
  /// displayHelpCenter will fail to load.
  Future<void> displayHelpCenter() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displayHelpCenter();
  }

  /// To log events in Intercom that record what users do in your app and when they do it.
  /// For example, you can record when user opened a specific screen in your app.
  /// You can also pass [metaData] about the event.
  Future<void> logEvent(String name, [Map<String, dynamic>? metaData]) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.logEvent(name, metaData);
  }

  /// The [token] to send to the Intercom to receive the notifications.
  ///
  /// For the Android, this [token] must be a FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) token.
  /// For the iOS, this [token] must be a APNS token.
  Future<void> sendTokenToIntercom(String token) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.sendTokenToIntercom(token);
  }

  /// When a user taps on a push notification Intercom hold onto data
  /// such as the URI in your message or the conversation to open.
  ///
  /// When you want Intercom to act on that data, use this method.
  Future<void> handlePushMessage() {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.handlePushMessage();
  }

  /// To open the Intercom messenger to the composer screen with [message]
  /// field pre-populated.
  Future<void> displayMessageComposer(String message) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displayMessageComposer(message);
  }

  /// To check if the push [message] is for Intercom or not.
  /// This is useful when your app is also configured to receive push messages
  /// from third parties.
  Future<bool> isIntercomPush(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.isIntercomPush(message);
  }

  /// If the push [message] is for Intercom then use this method to let
  /// Intercom handle that push.
  Future<void> handlePush(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.handlePush(message);
  }

  /// To display an Article, pass in an [articleId] from your Intercom workspace.
  ///
  /// An article must be ‘live’ to be used in this feature.
  /// If it is in a draft or paused state,
  /// end-users will see an error if the app tries to open the content.
  Future<void> displayArticle(String articleId) async {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displayArticle(articleId);
  }

  /// To display a Carousel, pass in a [carouselId] from your Intercom workspace.
  ///
  /// A carousel must be ‘live’ to be used in this feature.
  /// If it is in a draft or paused state,
  /// end-users will see an error if the app tries to open the content.
  Future<void> displayCarousel(String carouselId) async {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displayCarousel(carouselId);
  }

  /// To display a Survey, pass in a [surveyId] from your Intercom workspace.
  ///
  /// A survey must be ‘live’ to be used in this feature.
  /// If it is in a draft or paused state,
  /// end-users will see an error if the app tries to open the content.
  Future<void> displaySurvey(String surveyId) {
    return IntercomFlutterPlatform.instance.displaySurvey(surveyId);
  }
}
```

I have read similar questions on stack overflow and attempted the following to solve the 1st error :

```
await Intercom().initialize(appId,
iosApiKey: iosApiKey, androidApiKey: androidApiKey);
```

The errors now change to

```
The class 'Intercom' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
```

Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Intercom'.

I have run out of fixes.Kindly assist.

Comment: You can't call `Intercom()` because the constructor is private, but there is a static instance member you can use instead `Intercom.instance`. You can then call initialize on that: `await Intercom.instance.initialize(appId,
iosApiKey: iosApiKey, androidApiKey: androidApiKey);`

Comment: Thank you. This workded. Perhaps , you could post this as an answer for the community ?